# How to find the number of real roots for this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find the number of real roots that satisfy this equation:

```
f[g[x]] - h[f[x]] == (a)^2
```

Where:

```
f[x_] = x*Cos[x]
g[x_] = CubeRoot[-5 + (x)^2]
h[x_] = Abs[x + 2]
```

Where x is given as between the values of 0 and 5 i.e. [0,5]. And a is a parameter that i can change the value of.

What I have tried so far is to animate the function to just get a visual on the functions. I wrote this code:

```
Animate[Plot[{f[g[x]] - h[f[x]], (a)^2}, {x, 0, 5}], {a, 0, 1}]
```

I then wondered what might be the maximum value in this interval and I found it to be 0.511 when x = 2.4987. I used this code:

```
FindMaximum[{f[g[x]] - h[f[x]]}, {x, 2, 5}]
```

That value is given when a = 0.71499.

By a purely graphical analysis there are always two solutions to this equation at any one value of a when a is between the values of [0,0.71499). At a=0.71499 there is only one solution and beyond it there are no solutions.
Now how do I calculate the total number of roots to this equations?
I have tried the command CountRoots but it doesn't yield a result. Any other suggestions?

Comment: `CountRoots` expects a univariate function !

Answer (score 3):

`ContourPlot` gives you an idea of the answer I think

```
f[x_] = x*Cos[x]
g[x_] = CubeRoot[-5 + (x)^2]
h[x_] = Abs[x + 2]

pic=ContourPlot[f[g[x]] - h[f[x]] == (a)^2, {x, 0, 5}, {a, -1, 1}, FrameLabel -> {x, a}]
```

[image]

The peak-values follow from

```
mini = NMinimize[{a, f[g[x]] - h[f[x]] == (a)^2, Element[a, Reals]}, {x, a}] 
(*{-0.715053, {x -> 2.49876, a -> -0.715053}}*)
maxi = NMaximize[{a, f[g[x]] - h[f[x]] == (a)^2,Element[a, Reals]}, {x, a}] 
(*{0.714933, {x -> 2.49863, a -> 0.714933}}*)

amin=a/.mini[[2]]; (*-0.715053*)
amax=a/.maxi[[2]]; (*0.714933*)
```

As you can see from `ContourPlot`:

There exist two solutions if `amin<a<amax`
There exists one solutions if `a==amin or a==amax`
In all other cases there is no real solution

There exists no solution if `a>a/.maxi

Comment: It's clear the plot is symmetric with respect to `a`-axis since the function is even in `a`.

Comment: I am sorry but I dont understand. What is a contour plot, how exactly does it answer my question and how do I calculate the number of real roots with this information?

Comment: @IhabAlrikabi In my answer `ContourPlot[...]` plots all points `x,a` which fullfill the equation `f[g[x]] - h[f[x]] == (a)^2`

Comment: Oh ok I understand its purpose now but I dont see how I should use this info to calculate the number of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can try FindInstance:

```
FindInstance[f[g[x]] - h[f[x]] == a^2, {a, x}, Reals]
```

And

```
FindInstance[f[g[x]] - h[f[x]] == a^2, {a, x}, Complexes]
```

Each of these yielded one solution, both outside your outside domain.  Neither found multiple solutions, but that is limited by the methods available to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the result of

```
f[x_] = x*Cos[x];g[x_] = CubeRoot[-5 + (x)^2] ;h[x_] = Abs[x + 2];
ContourPlot[{f[g[x]] - h[f[x]] == (a)^2}, {x, 0, 5}, {a, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

to this end.

Addition.

```
ContourPlot[{f[g[x]] - h[f[x]] == (a)^2}, {x, -50, 50}, {a, -5,5 },PlotPoints->100]
```

[image]